# MongooseError: `Model.findByIdAndUpdate()` cannot run without a model as `this`. Make sure you are not calling `new Model.findByIdAndUpdate()`

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

This is how I connected to the database

```
const dbConnection = async() => {
try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_CNN);
    console.log('Base de datos online');
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw new Error('Error al inicializar la base de datos');
}
```

the problem comes when updating

```
const usuariosPut = (req = request, res = response) => {
const {id} = req.params;
const {password, google, correo, ...resto} = req.body;
if (password) {
    const salt = bcryptjs.genSaltSync();
    resto.password = bcryptjs.hashSync(password, salt);
}
const usuario = new Usuario.findByIdAndUpdate(id, resto);
res.json({
    msg: 'put API - controlador',
    id
});
```

I get that error, it would be very helpful since I just started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are trying to create a new instance of the model model rather than directly calling the method on the model.

```
const usuario = new Usuario.findByIdAndUpdate(id, resto);
```

should be:

```
const usuario = await Usuario.findByIdAndUpdate(id, resto);
```

Additionally, I don't see any `async` keyword or `Promise.then()` in your code. Model methods are asyncronous, so make sure to mark your main function `async` like this:

```
const usuariosPut = async (req = request, res = response) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you created `Usuario` model before? If so, you do not need to call model constructor with `new` keyword, your code should look like this:

```js
const usuario = await Usuario.findByIdAndUpdate(id, resto);
```